# How to define DataGrid ComboBox column that shows choice of color rectangles from RGB values?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I  managed to define column that shows available color index (int) values in combobox. Instead of color index I should show a rectangle filled with color defined by color's RGB-values.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="SelectionSets" CanUserAddRows="False" 
        CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectionSets}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSelectionSet}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="{StaticResource XpStrColor}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ColorIndex}" 
                       SelectedValuePath="Index" DisplayMemberPath="Index">
                  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                       <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                              <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Colors}"/>
                              <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                       </Style>
                  </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                       <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                              <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Colors}"/>
                       </Style>
                 </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
          </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Below ViewModel is my own class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and SetValue raises the event.

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<DrawingColor> _colors;
    public ObservableCollection<DrawingColor> Colors
    {
        get { return _selectionSets; }
        set { this.SetValue(ref _colors, value); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SelectionSetViewModel> _selectionSets;
    public ObservableCollection<SelectionSetViewModel> SelectionSets
    {
        get { return _selectionSets; }
        set { this.SetValue(ref _selectionSets, value); }
    }

    private SelectionSetViewModel _selectedSelectionSet;
    public SelectionSetViewModel SelectedSelectionSet
    {
        get { return this._selectedSelectionSet; }
        set { this.SetValue(ref _selectedSelectionSet, value); }
    }
}
```

Class for one row:

```
public class SelectionSetViewModel : ViewModel
{
    //...

    private int _colorIndex;
    public int ColorIndex
    {
        get { return _colorIndex; }
        set { SetValue(ref _colorIndex, value); }
    }
    //...
 }
```

Class for color:

```
    public class DrawingColor
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public Byte R { get; set; }
        public Byte G { get; set; }
        public Byte B { get; set; }
    }
```

So the DataContext and class-structure works already.

I also (kind of) know how to show color rectangle in ComboBox:

```
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Rectangle Height="10" Width="80">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color ="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColorIndexToColorConverter}}"/>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Converter

```
public class ColorIndexToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (((DrawingColor)value).Index == -1 || ((DrawingColor)value).Index == -10)
            return Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
        else
            return Color.FromArgb(255, ((DrawingColor)value).R, ((DrawingColor)value).G, ((DrawingColor)value).B);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

However I did not understand how to combine DataTemplete with the example that has DataGridComboBoxColumn containing DisplayMemberPath and DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it as part of the ComboBox style. Like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="{StaticResource XpStrColor}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ColorIndex}" 
        SelectedValuePath="Index" DisplayMemberPath="Index">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Colors}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Rectangle Height="10" Width="80">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color ="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColorIndexToColorConverter}}"/>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Colors}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Rectangle Height="10" Width="80">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color ="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColorIndexToColorConverter}}"/>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

To fix the cast exception, check if the value is a DrawingColor in your converter. Return null if it isn't. Like this:

```
public class ColorIndexToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is DrawingColor))
            return null;
        if (((DrawingColor)value).Index == -1 || ((DrawingColor)value).Index == -10)
            return Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
        else
            return Color.FromArgb(255, ((DrawingColor)value).R, ((DrawingColor)value).G, ((DrawingColor)value).B);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! it looks sensible. i'll try this later today.

Comment: this results: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ZzzXXX.dll
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'DrawingColor'. when clocking combobox column. There seems to be no Combobox anymore.

Comment: thanks! I can try that tomorrow morning latest. I just wonder how this fixes the problem where converter parameter value is of wrong type. i mean isn't it always string? however cast in converter is probably the source of exception and i can report the results later.

Comment: I think you mean converter value not parameter (you're not passing a parameter). And no, it isn't always a string. I think maybe it's just that it is still setting things up so the first couple of calls are passing in default values instead of your DrawingColor. In VisualStudio 2015, go to menu Tools->Options. Then open up Debugging and select Output Window. Under the WPF Trace Settings, change Data Binding to All. When you run the program, you will see all the binding information/errors in the Output window.

Comment: Convert-method's 1st parameter is called "value" == parameter value. I meant that. Anyway you are right. Now I get the colors. Thanks!

Comment: Actually SelectionSetViewModel.ColorIndex is not updated when i choose a line in ComboBox. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have time right now but I noticed it did update after the combobox lost focus.